# How to prove the convergence of the sеquence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Can`t find the proof of the convergence on $\mathbb{R}$ of this sequence:

$$x_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{mn}\right)^{m+n},m \in {\mathbb{R}-\{0\}} $$
Please help.

Comment: When what tends to what?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean. These are all conditions of the problem. (added convergence on R)

Comment: Hint: separate the power.

Comment: What have you tried? You have already asked quite a few questions here, so you should already known that without mentioning any attempts to solve the problem the question is not usually well accepted.

Comment: Usually I write that I tried, but in this case I don`t know even from what to start.

Comment: I am not convinced looking at your previous questions. But anyway a suggestion: writting "I don't know where to start" has more value than writting "Please help" (but not by much, it's always better to mention at least some thoughts, I am sure you have some).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that $m \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ is fixed and we are letting $n\to\infty$:

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{mn}\right)^{m+n} = \left(1+\frac{1}{mn}\right)^{m}\cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{mn}\right)^{n}
\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} (1+0)^m \cdot e^{\frac1m}
= e^\frac1m
$$

Because if $m > 0$ then:

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{mn}\right)^{n} = \left(1+\frac{1}{mn}\right)^{mn\cdot\frac1m} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} e^\frac1m$$

and if $m < 0$ then:

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{mn}\right)^{n} = \left(1-\frac{1}{|m|n}\right)^{|m|n\cdot\frac1{|m|}} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} e^{-\frac1{|m|}} = e^\frac1m$$